# Spring: dependent properties stored in a file

Tags: java, spring, properties

I'm stuck with a problem reading properties from a file, I think I'm missing something really stupid but i cannot get what.

I read a property file and inject the values where needed with "@Value" annotation.
I have my property file that looks like this:

```
my.property.A=valueA
my.property.B=${my.property.A}

otherPropertyA=other
otherPropertyB=${otherPropertyA}
```

What happens is that the value of "otherPropertyB" is set correctly, in the java code i use the expected value.
But the property "my.property.B" is an empty string.

The difference i see is that the first property has dots in its name, i tried to escape them but i didn't find a way to do it.

Does someone knows what i'm missing there?

Comment: You could check if there is another `my.property.A` in another `.properties` file, maybe it is overwritten due to the order in which `@PropertySource()` are in your config.

Comment: Try injecting the Spring `Environment` into a class and testing that `environment.getProperty("my.property.B")` is not null.  The dot notation should not be a problem, this is standard syntax.  The problem is likely elsewhere in the `@Value` assignment.

Comment: Stefan you were right...there was a wrong property with the same name with an empty string value.. :/